# How to "Undo" after the Excel addin updated the worksheet

Tags: office-js

Suppose the Excel addin updated the worksheet (e.g., format, add new data). ctrl-z does not undo such updates. Implementing a separate undo that is only available within the add-in is the only way?

Comment: in Office JS, the undo stack is cleared when JS API was called. and this behavior is as same as VBA. we have a work item to track this requirement. but due to this behavior is as same as VBA. we would like to learn from you and to justify this work.  I would like to consult with you: do you have VBA add-in?  if yes, how you handle this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

ctrl-z undo is not supported in Excel (just as any VBA/VSTO instructions). This is not the same in Word, where ctrl-z does work.